Give access to Agent EmailTemplate Reference Object
I am using the using Einstein Co Pilot in a demo Salesforce Org. In the conversation preview I am asking the agent to return a list of all the templates but it is not returning any results.
I checked my permission sets but I am still a bit confused - is there a way to give einstein co pilot access to a specific object - specifically the EmailTemplate object.
I want my agent to be able return a list of the email templates I have created and parse the code to make changes


The Agent will run with the permissions of the running user, so if you have access the Agent should as well. If that isn't possible, you could also create a custom action that calls a Flow or Apex running in System Mode.
